# How can I get my dual monitors to work in Windows 7, after no online solutions work?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi

I will start by saying this is the first time I have tried to perform this particular task, however, I am an IT professional, and I do know my way around a computer.

The problem is I can't "extend" my desktop to two monitors, no matter what I try.

**Things I've Tried:**

Plugging both VGA connectors (one needs a DVI converter) into the motherboard video card.

*Fails Because--Windows 7 Doesn't detect a second monitor.*

Plugging both VGA connectors (one needs a DVI converter) into an external video card (MSI RX300HM(V032)).

*Fails Because--Windows 7 Doesn't detect a second monitor.*

Plugging one VGA connector into the external video card and the other VGA connector into the motherboard video card (using no DVI converters).

*Fails Because--Windows 7 Doesn't detect a second monitor.*

Making sure I have the most updated drivers for the video card (and monitors, where Windows will detect it), then trying all of the above, again.

*Fails Because--All of the same reasons, stated above.*

Checking the monitors and making sure they work separately.

*They both work fine. In fact, when I plug them both into the external video card, they both display the same "duplicate" screen.*

Forcing Windows to output to "No Display Detected" but it just puts "what it thinks" is the second monitor, off in the blank void to the left of my other two monitors.

Downloading ATI CCC and trying to manage it that way.

*Fails Because--There is no "Desktop Manager* link (the link I am lead to believe will lead to the configuration screen for dual monitors and such). Also, this is not the only place therein that I checked. I scoured that interface for configurations suitable to change such settings, but all to no avail.

It may be relevant (although, hopefully not) to note that the two monitors aren't the same brand (one is Acer and the other is Philips).

Also, it is important to note that I "rebooted" my machine between all of the major steps listed above.

**What else could be the issue?**

Aren't all relatively new video cards supporting dual monitors these days? (I am beginning to think they don't, as that seems the only reasonable explanation to my dilemma).

Comment: Did you reboot after plugging in the second monitor?  I know some video cards don't automatically accept the (initial) second monitor without a reboot.

Comment: @Kruug Oh, sry, yes, several times (pretty much between all of the major steps, stated above). I will edit my post to include that bit of info. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: `using no DVI converters` if there's a DVI slot why were you using VGA adapters? This is a long shot since I never had any troubles with it, but you could check your BIOS to see if there isn't any options related to it.

Comment: @Alex Well, I only used `no DVI converters` when I tried one monitor hooked up to the external video card and the other monitor hooked up to the motherboard video card (since they each have one VGA port). I still would need the DVI adapter when trying to plug both monitors into the same video card (whether it's the external card or the internal card).

Comment: Are you on a laptop or desktop? And what is your graphics card/chipset?

Comment: @BenRichards A desktop. I believe my Video card type and version is stated in my question.

Comment: @VoidKing I tried googling that PIN and "MSI V032" to no avail. All I see are driver downloads from third-party sites. Can you link to the product page?

Comment: @BenRichards It is possible I got the wrong number. Give me a bit to see if I can locate the real number you need (if I can find the product page, I will just send you the link.)

Comment: Did you check to see if it was identifying a generic non-plug & play monitor in device manager? It's probably not there since W7 is saying it can't detect second monitor. But it's a quick check. If it does show up try updating the driver...

Comment: It has only been displaying one monitor in Device Manager since this whole thing began.

Comment: Ok, they both show the same screen when plugged into the video card.  Did you go into `Screen Resolution` and click `Detect`?  Some of the computers I work with need that step as well.

Comment: @Kruug OHHHH yes, many millions of times (exaggeration-o-meter in the red) LOL, but yeah, if the answer was that simple, I would have actually gotten some real work done today :)

Comment: @BenRichards Okay, Yeah, I think I got the number wrong (will update) but it is one of the two you will find in this link:  http://1887047.sites.myregisteredsite.com/index.php?func=searchresult&keywords=RX300HM  However, I'm pretty sure it is the (DDR2) version.

Comment: Also, I'm not gonna down-vote you because, at least you're trying to help, but don't you think this post would be better as a comment, since it is not really an answer?

Comment: @VoidKing I see it, thanks. Looking up more info. I was initially curious if CCC didn't work because it was an nVidia card, but it's not. CCC not showing anything might be because it's a very old card and the CCC software may not support managing it.

Comment: @BenRichards Perhaps, but I know it's not 'that' old. I would find it hard to believe that it was too old to either be included in the CCC interface or too old to not support dual monitors, however, I would also have found it hard to believe I would have this much trouble doing something so seemingly simple, so who knows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the user manual for that card (which is downloadable via the [product page on MSI.com](http://www.msi.com/product/vga/RX300HM-TD128E.html#?div=Manual), if you look at the diagram of the card on page 2, it states under an asterisk:

> The DVI-I port and D-Sub port of this card do not support dual monitor.

DSUB refers to the VGA connector (which is part of the DSUB connector family).

So it seems that you might be out of luck trying to get dual monitors to work with this card. It seems to just simply not support it.

By the way, CCC might not allow you do manage the display settings for this card because it's a very old card, and recent versions of CCC may not be compatible with its drivers. According to the product page, it's powered by the "ATI® RADEON® X300SE GPU". That card uses the RV370 GPU, which, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_X300-X600_Series), was released in 2005. That's 8 years ago, which is ancient in computer timeframes.

Comment: Okay, I will see if my organization has another video card available. Thank you for your professional and patient help. I have been pulling my hair out all day with this. Apparently support for dual monitors wasn't as recently universally supported as I thought.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you are a gentleman and a scholar :)

Comment: @VoidKing You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully at the card, you will see that the cable connects the vga to the dvi port. Also, the manual for the RX300 "lite" states that the card does not support dual monitors.

So it looks like you have a single output with a vga-dvi adapter built into the card.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you have the right answer, but I had to give it to Ben because he has been helping me narrow this down for a bit now (I still gave you +1, though, cause you are "right").